# PIG : how to separate data by positions in a single line

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

normally if we there any delimiter in a line we do.

```
load "pigtest.txt" using PigStorage(',') as (year:int,temp:float);
```

Below is the sample whether data of single line.

```
0029029070999991901010106004+64333+023450FM12+000599999V0202701N015919999999N0000001N9-00781+99999102001ADDGF108991999999999999999999
```

I need to extract year `1901(16th position to 4positions)` t`emperature(89th position to 4 positions)` so that i can define my key and value.

I also need to trim initial zeroes from temperature.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have any code attempting a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use `FixedWidthLoader`UDF to extract the specific position from input data. Download `piggybank.jar` and try the below approach.

**input**

```
0029029070999991901010106004+64333+023450FM12+000599999V0202701N015919999999N0000001N9-00781+99999102001ADDGF108991999999999999999999
```

**PigScript:**

```
REGISTER /tmp/piggybank.jar;
A = LOAD 'input' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.FixedWidthLoader('16-19,89-92') AS(year:int,temp:float);
DUMP A;
```

**Output:**

```
(1901,781.0)
```

**Reference:**
http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/FixedWidthLoader.html